# Regular expression: How to name a group using match result

Tags: python, regex

I want to name a group using the result of matched group. For example in python:

**I want :**

```
import re

match = re.search(WHAT_I_NEED, 'name = tom')
assert match.groupdict()['name'] == 'tom'
if match.groupdict() == {'name': 'tom'}:
    print('better')
```

**I have tried:**

```
import re

WHAT_I_NEED = r'(?P<attr_name>\w+) = (?P<(?P=attr_name)>\w+)'

match = re.search(WHAT_I_NEED, 'name = tom')
```

I get:

`sre_constants.error: bad character in group name '(?P=attr_name)'`

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323) - what are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign group names in the regex dynamically. But you can do something like this:

```
>>> data = "name = tom, age = 12, language = Python"
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?P<key>\w+) = (?P<value>\w+)")
>>> matches = {k: v for k,v in regex.findall(data)}
>>> matches
{'age': '12', 'language': 'Python', 'name': 'tom'}
```